# How can I reduce the amount of code I have written to move my character in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, accelerometer, performance

I am building a infinite vertical platformer for mobile platforms using Unity3D. I am using the accelerometer to move the character left and right on the screen. So far I have this:

```
if (Input.acceleration.y > -0.2f && Input.acceleration.y < 0.2f) {
                        maxSpeed = 17;
                }

        if (Input.acceleration.y > -0.5f && Input.acceleration.y < -0.2f) {
            maxSpeed = 25;
        }
        if (Input.acceleration.y > 0.2f && Input.acceleration.y < 0.5f) {
            maxSpeed = 25;
        }
        if (Input.acceleration.y > -0.7f && Input.acceleration.y < -0.5f) {
            maxSpeed = 25;
        }
        if (Input.acceleration.y > 0.5f && Input.acceleration.y < 0.9f) {
            maxSpeed = 25;
        }
        if (Input.acceleration.y < -0.9f) {
            maxSpeed = 40;
        }
        if (Input.acceleration.y  > 0.9f) {
            maxSpeed = 40;
        }
```

Basically the farther the device is tilted the faster the character moves. I'm pretty sure there is a way better way to write this code but I'm pretty terrible at math and I can't figure it out. Any suggestions to clean this up a bit?

Comment: Working code should be evaluated on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)  Its off topic for SO.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class/struct which holds the acceleration limits and the maximum speed. Create an array of those and add the values. Then loop through the array and check if the limits match.

Something like this:

```
public struct AccelerationValue {
    public float min;
    public float max;
    public int speed;

    public AccelerationValue(float mn, float mx, int s) {
        min = mn;
        max = mx;
        speed = s;
    }
}

void Start () {
    AccelerationValue[] accelerationValues = {
                                                 new AccelerationValue(-0.2f, 0.2f, 17),
                                                 new AccelerationValue(-0.5f, -0.2f, 25)
                                             };

    foreach (AccelerationValue v in accelerationValues)
    {
        if (Input.acceleration.y > v.min && Input.acceleration.y < v.max)
        {
            maxSpeed = v.speed;
        }
    }
}
```